# Web scraping issue searching for contents in Youtube trending page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to build an app that returns the top 10 youtube trending videos into an excel file but ran into an issue right at the beginning. For some reason, whenever I try to use "soup.find" on any of the id's on this YouTube page, it returns "None" as the result.

I have made sure that my spelling is perfect and everything but it still won't work. I have tried this same code using other sites and get the same error.

```
#What I did for Youtube which resulted in output being "None"
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
videos = soup.find(id= "contents")

print(videos)
```

I expect it to provide me with the HTML code that has this id that I have specified but it keeps saying "None".

Answer (score 0):

The page is using heavy Javascript to modify class, attributes of tags. What you see in Developer Tools isn't always what `requests` provides you. I recommend to call `print(soup.prettify())` and see with what markup you're working with.

You can use this script to get first 10 trending videos:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


for i, a in enumerate(soup.select('h3.yt-lockup-title a[title]')[:10], 1):
    print('{: <4}{}'.format(str(i)+'.', a['title']))
```

Prints (in my case in Estonia):

```
1.  Jaanus Saks - Su säravad silmad
2.  Егор Крид - Сердцеедка (Премьера клипа, 2019)
3.  Comment Out #11/ Ольга Бузова х Фёдор Смолов
4.  5MIINUST x NUBLU - (ei ole) aluspükse
5.  Артур Пирожков - Алкоголичка (Премьера клипа 2019)
6.  Slav school of driving - driving instructor Boris
7.  ЧТО ЕДЯТ В АРМИИ США VS РОССИИ?
8.  RC Airplane Battle | Dude Perfect
9.  ЧЕЙ КОРАБЛИК ОСТАНЕТСЯ ПОСЛЕДНИЙ, ПОЛУЧИТ 1000$ !
10. Khloé Kardashian's New Mom Beauty Routine | Beauty Secrets | Vogue
```

Answer (score 0):

Since YouTube uses too much of javascript to render and modify the way pages load, it's a better idea to make the page load in a browser and then use it's page source for rendering in BeautifulSoup scripts. So we use **Selenium** for this purpose. Here once the soup object is obtained then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import os
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/rishabh/Documents/pythonProjects/webScarapping/geckodriver")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending')
content = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
#Do whatever you want with it
```

Configure Selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html